# Innodb not started?

Tags: mysql, innodb, galera, wsrep

I installed MariaDB_Galera_server10.0 , but when i check the error log i see this:

```
170118 14:49:09 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
170118 14:49:09 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
170118 14:49:09 [Note] InnoDB: Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com)    5.6.34-79.1 sta
rted; log sequence number 1627308
170118 14:49:09 [Note] Plugin ‘FEEDBACK’ is disabled.
170118 14:49:09 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
170118 14:49:10 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
170118 14:49:10 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
170118 14:49:10 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170118 14:49:10 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing   of buffer po
170118 14:49:11 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number   1627318
```

this is the cluster configuration '/etc/mysql/conf.d/cluster.cnf' :

```
[mysqld]

query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/Lib64/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=32G"
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.10.231, 192.168.10.233
wsrep_sst_method= rsync
wsrep_sst_auth = wsrep_sst_user:wsrep_sst_pass
wsrep_node_address='192.168.10.231'
wsrep_node_name="yasoo"
```

and my.cnf :

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
# You can copy this file to one of:
- “/etc/mysql/my.cnf’ to set global options,
# - “—/.my.cnf” to set user-specific options.
# One can use all, long options that the program supports.
# Run program with - -help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
# For explanations see
# http://dev .mysql .com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain “#‘ chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

[client]

port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# This was formally known as [safe_mysqid] . Both versions are currently parsed.

[mysqld_safe]
log-bin=/var/log/mysql-bin.log
log=/var/tog/mysql.log
#1og-error= /var/log/mysqld.error.log
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice =0

[mysqid]
#* Basic Settings
user = mysql
pid - file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/1ib/mysql
tmpdir = ltmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#* Fine Tuning
max_connections = 100
connect_timeout = 5
wait_timeout = 600
max-allowed_packet = 16M
thread_cache_size = 128
sort_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
#* MyISAM
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP

key_buffer_size = 128M
#open-files-limit = 2000
table_open_cache = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert = 2
read buffer size = 2M
read md buffer size = 1M
#* Query Cache Configuration
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit = 128K

# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type = DEMAND
* Logging and Replication
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime’
general_log_file = /var/log/mysqi/mysql.log
general_log = 1
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#1og-bin=/var/log/mysql-bin .log
#1og=/var/log/mysqi.1og
#]og-error= /var/log/mysqld.error.iog
# we do want to know about network errors and such
]og_warnings = 2
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={O 1})
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10

log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
#log -queries -not -using -indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication sl.ave, see README.Debian about
other settings you may need to change.
server-id = 121
#report_host = masterl
#auto_inc rement_inc rement = 2
#auto_increment_offset = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index = /var/log/mysql/ma riadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = lOOM
# slaves
relay_log = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
relay_log_index = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
log_slave_updates


# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
* InnoDB
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
# you can’t just change log file size, requires special procedure
nnodb_log_file_size = SOM
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 400
innodb_io_capacity = 400
innodb flush method = 0_DIRECT

#* Security Features
# Read the manu&L, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lJb/mysql/
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI “tinyca”.
# ssl. -ca=/etc/mysql/cace rt . pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert .pem
# ssl -key=/etc/mysql/server-key .pem

#*Galera-related settings
[galera]

#Mandatory settings

log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err
log -bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-replication.og
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#bind-address=G.O.O.O
# Optional setting
wsrep_slave_threads=16
#innodb_flush_tog_at_trx_commit=0
[mysqidump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M
[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysq1. but no tab completion

[isamchkJ
key_buffer = 16M

*# IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
# The files must end with ‘.cnf’, otherwise they’ll be ignored.

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Please add the command you used to start Galera to the question. Also, you might move the `wsrep_slave_threads=16` setting to the galera config file just to keep them all in the same place.

Comment: service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of these typos are causing it to croak:

```
#]og-error= /var/log/mysqld.error.iog
# we do want to know about network errors and such
]og_warnings = 2
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={O 1})
...
nnodb_log_file_size = SOM
log -bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-replication.og
#bind-address=G.O.O.O
[isamchkJ
```

(There may be more!)

Unless you have a tiny amount of RAM, this should be more like 70% of RAM:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
```

Comment: these typos caused because of bad copying way (from the terminal to here) they r not as in real..